# How to downgrade to a older kernel

Tags: updates, wifi, kernel, drivers

I inadvertently updated my Linux kernel to version 4.2.0-30 from 3.19.0-33 and it has broken my WiFi and USB drivers, is there a way for me to downgrade my kernel using some sort of cached version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.2.0-30-generic` in terminal to remove the new 4.2 kernel.Then reboot

WARNING : If you have removed your old kernel using `apt-get` or synaptic this can result in an unbootable computer

Answer (score 1):

You really do not need to do this right now
when booting ...

- get to the grub menu when booting
- select the previous kernel
- run it

at this point see if the WiFi and USB work
If so THEN you can remove the kernel if it bothers you

Comment: This is what I also do. However, I use Linux on my home PC and grub automatically loads the latest kernel and my PC boots up my session automatically. That's why it is better to roll back to an older kernel is the best for a person like me.